# How do I retrieve data stored with JS dot notation from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, syntax, store

I have a script that stores data in an LI element, with JS, with

```
testel = document.getElementById('#myLi');
testel.angle = 20;
```

How do I retrieve that value with JQ?
I tried creating a new reference to the element like `$('#testel').angle` or `$('#testel').data('angle')` but nothing works.

Where is that data stored? Is it even possible?

Comment: `$('#myLi').get(0).angle` or `$(testel).get(0).angle` or `$(testel)[0].angle` BTW, it should be: `document.getElementById('myLi');`

Comment: When asking question, please provide relevant code, not irrelevant which obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I retrieve that value with JQ?

Two ways:

1. Get it from the raw DOM element:

   ```
   var a = $('#testel')[0].angle;
   //                  ^^^-------- Gets the raw DOM element from the jQuery object

   var a = $('#testel').get(0).angle;
   //                  ^^^^^^^-------- This does too
   ```
2. Use `prop`:

   ```
   var a = $('#testel').prop('angle');
   ```

> Where is that data stored?

That's called an "expando" property. It's stored on the raw DOM element. It's generally best to avoid using them when you can (to avoid conflicting with new standard properties that may be defined, to avoid conflicting with other scripts on the page). When you can't, it's best to use just *one* of them (usually referring to an object that you put other properties on if you need more information).

> I tried creating a new reference to the element like `$('#testel').angle` or `$('#testel').data('angle')` but nothing works.

jQuery's `data` function stores information in a different area (to avoid expando issues). If you can, I'd suggest changing the code *setting* the value to set it via jQuery's `data`:

```
$('#testel').data('angle', 20);
```

...and then of course you can retrieve it the same way:

```
var a = $('#testel').data('angle');
```

---

As [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) points out in a comment below, your code is a bit mismatched. You say you're doing this to set it:

```
testel = document.getElementById('#myLi');
testel.angle = 20;
```

...but then trying to use this to retrieve it:

```
$("#testel").angle // (and such)
```

Your `getElementById` code looks for an element with the ID `#myLi` (**including** the `#` at the beginning, as part of the `id`). While that's valid (you can do that in HTML; not in CSS), it's relaly unlikely you actually have:

```
<li id="#myLi">...</li>
```

in your document. You probably don't want the `#` in the `getElementById` call. (What you give `getElementById` is an ID string, not a CSS selector).

Regardless, you'll want the `id` you use when setting and when retrieving to match. So if it's `myLi`, use `getElementById("myLi")` and `$("#myLi")`.

Comment: But OP posted code is ambiguous because firstly is JS code is wrong and is using an object not an element with ID attribute testel. I mean this will return empty object: `$('#testel')`

Comment: @A.Wolff: It's true that the IDs don't match, I'll flag that up. The code is valid, and the OP is clearly trying to use an element to store this.

Comment: It could be valid but i don't think so: `document.getElementById('#myLi');` Anyway +1 for great answer as usual. {I mean i guess it'll return no matched element}

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yeah, it's really unlikely that the OP has `<li id="#myLi">...</li>` in their document. :-)

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake by quick writing the example with mismatching IDs, but hopefully most of you got the idea. Thanks everyone's help. I found out in the developers tools in chrome that the value was under [0] when logging the object to the console, just after I quit searching for it in the actual DOM because there was SO much info… but nowhere the "angle" value.

Comment: @sergio: (Yeah, I read right past the mismatch.) Ah, good point -- the value *is* in the DOM (as a property on the element), but it isn't shown in the DOM tree in the DOM inspector like an attribute would be. (It **is** shown if you use the DOM inspector's list of properties on the object -- buried in amongst the dozens of other properties...)

Answer (score 2):

By using [array dereferencing operator](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$('#testel')[0].angle
```

Or by using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('#testel').prop("angle")
```

Comment: Short and concise. I would have chosen this one if it wasn't because T.J.'s extensive answer covering all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the underlying DOM element:

```
var angle = $("#testel").get(0).angle;
```

Or using array indexing:

```
var angle = $("#testel")[0].angle;
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added to answer. Other than brevity, are there any other benefits to this?

Comment: @ RGraham: It's a property access rather than a function call, like using `length` rather than `size()`. That's not likely to matter, though. Mostly, brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting one attribute for that element, so use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#testel').attr('angle')
```

Comment: It's not an attribute, it's a property.

Comment: Might work with earlier versions of jQuery but not with 1.6+.

Comment: I don't know if property or attribute, but I just know it has to be accessed quickly from different functions, to calculate the x and y of 16 objects fast enough to make a worm-like smooth animation.
I tried to avoid to write it to the actual DOM because I've read that traversing the DOM to retrieve it is slower (and obviously I don't understand js or jq enough yet to asseverate data.('angle') isn't also traversing the DOM, but oh well, "I might not know where I need to go but I know what I'm running away from".